# How do i get "fail" to be displayed with JQuery animation fail function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a slider and i want that when the elements of the slider run out, for example, when clicking right and nothing happens because there no more elements it prints "fail". I m using this:
this might help: [codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMxevp](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMxevp)

```js
$('#status_bar').animate({
            left: "+=500px"
        }, {
            duration: 3000,
            specialEasing: {
                width: "linear",
                height: "easeOutBounce"
            },
            complete: function () {
                console.log("complete")
            },
            fail: function () {
                console.log("fail")
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to check position or other conditions before calling `animate()`. It has no idea why you are calling it

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I didn't understood how do i make this work. My div with status_bar id contains mulltiple others div's (images).

Comment: Not enough shown to know what problem is to be honest

Comment: this might help: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZMxevp